# Calculating the convolution of a matrix with a recursive subroutine in Fortran 2003

Tags: algorithm, recursion, matrix, fortran, fortran2003

I've never asked a question here, so please let me know if I am describing my problem enough.

I'm pretty new at Fortran and I wanted to create a recursive subroutine that would compute each square of a 3 x 3 matrix. If you are not familiar with convolution, this is a good resource: http://songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution2d_example.html.
I used the same values in this example to make sure I was doing it right.

The purpose of the program is to have the recursive subroutine called in the middle of two do loops (indexes both go from [0,2]). When the recusive function is called, it will find the sum of all the products of **one** square of the output matrix. The loops will call it 9 times to ensure that every square's value has been calculated to produce the desired output. Well, after much editing on paper, I thought that I had a pretty good idea that the subroutine would work and it seems that only the first square (0,0) was able to get its answer, -13.

I believe my problem has to do with the assignments in the subroutine. I want to continue calling the next 'temp' value to add it to the total, which will be returned to the program calling it.

Depending on the current i and j values, there might not be any multiplication needed for every turn through the recursive method, so I wanted the subroutine to find a way to continue adding temp if that was the case.

```
program conprac
  implicit none

  integer, dimension(0:2,0:2) :: mat1(0:2,0:2) = reshape((/1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9/),(/3,3/))
  integer, dimension(0:2,0:2) :: totals(0:2,0:2) = 0
  integer, dimension(2,2) :: kernal(0:2,0:2) = reshape((/1,0,-1,2,0,-2,1,0,-1/),(/3,3/))
  integer :: i=0, j=0, this_total=0, total=0, m=0, n=0, k=0

  !do m = 0,0
    !do n = 0,1
        total = 0
        call calc(kernal, mat1, i, j, m, n, this_total, total)
        totals(m,n) = total
    !end do
  !end do

  write(*,*) "totals(0,0): ", totals(0,0) !-13
  !write(*,*) "totals(0,1): ", totals(0,1)  !-20

end program conprac

recursive subroutine calc(kernal, mat, i, j, addToi, addToj, this_total, total)
 implicit none 

 !declare calling parameter types and definitions

 !to calculate with
 integer, intent(in), dimension(0:2,0:2) :: kernal, mat

 integer, intent(in) :: addToi, addToj
 integer, intent(out) :: i, j, this_total

 !to calculate
 integer, intent(out) :: total

 !temp variable
 integer :: temp

 if (i <= 2) then
    if (j > 2) then
        i = i + 1
        j = 0
    end if

    if ((i + addToi) - 1 < 0 .or. (j + addToj) - 1 < 0 .or. (i + addToi) - 1 > 2 .or. (j + addToj) - 1 > 2) then

        j = j+1

        call calc(kernal, mat, i, j, addToi, addToj, this_total, temp)

        total = total + temp
        write(*,*) "total1: ", total
    else
        this_total = kernal(i,j) * mat((i + addToi) - 1, (j + addToj) - 1)

        j = j+1

        call calc(kernal, mat, i, j, addToi, addToj, this_total, temp)

        total = this_total + temp
        write(*,*) "total2: ", total        
    end if


 end if
end subroutine calc
```

As of right now, the do loops are commented out so I can test one value at a time up where m, n are initialized.

The parameters for the subroutine are: kernal and mat being the 2 matricies, i and j both starting at 0 when the subroutine is called, m and n values being what is added to i and j respectively to make sure that the kernal is shifted and not calculating in the same spot for all 9 squares. this_total is a holder for the product of an overlapping square to be added to the returning value total, and total is the value returned and will be sent to the totals array in the program. For the first one, it would be at index (m,n), or (0,0).

These are the outputs for the first square in totals: 
[m=0,n=0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii4GN.png)

Comment: Please copy the output as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Are you wedded to using a recursive subroutine ?  If not, think of placing a *halo* of `0`-valued cells around your input array, so that it is `(0:5,0:5)` with all outermost cells set to `0`.  Then write a double-loop over `1,3` in each direction and do a little multiplication -- you could even write a little helper function to do the multiplication/addition for you.  This is a very widely used technique which saves a lot of fiddly edge-case processing.

Comment: I realise that where I wrote `(0:5,0:5)` in my previous comment I should have written `(0:4,0:4)`.  Just another Fortran programmer having trouble counting from `0` ...

Comment: Yes, I thought that is what you meant. Thank you for the reply.